# How to open the concrete article in Zendesk Widget?

Tags: javascript, zendesk, zendesk-api

Is it possible to open the concrete article using Help Center API in Zendesk Widget? When user clicks on some label, I would like:

1. Open Zendesk widget.
2. Fill the placeholder with the clicked label text.
3. Load and show the article that contains descriptions for all labels.

I've tried to do that:

```
window.zE('webWidget', 'open');
window.zE('webWidget', 'helpCenter:setSuggestions', {
  search: `Glossary ${search}`
});
```

but it just opens a widget and shows the first three articles (the first article is that I want to show).

I will appreciate any help or advice how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is actually expected. The reason being for the 3 article postings is because it's part of the Web Widget's contextual help feature Zendesk has put into their platform. Using setSuggestions is going to display the first three articles. What I would suggest using is { labels: ['label1'] } and add labels to articles that you will want to appear depending on where the user clicks on your web widget. Also, it might be best to review your end goal and check through the API provided to see if its exactly possible to achieve the nature of your request.

Cheers,